# Android theme error's

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I want make new theme for my app (one theme before `< v21` and one theme `>=v21` and higher).

This is code from `Activity`:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.DriverNotesAppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tool_bar_test);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

XML-layout toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/DriverNotesAppTheme"
    app:theme="@style/DriverNotesAppTheme">
```

This is theme before `v21`:

```
<style name="DriverNotesAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_bg</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/edittext_primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>
</style>
```

This is theme for `v21` and higher:

```
<style name="DriverNotesAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_bg</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/edittext_primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>
</style>
```

And this is screenshots:
[image]
`v21` and higher;

[image]

before `v21`

And colors from resources:
[image]

Comment: thats exactly you got from your theme. What you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @johnrao07 colors like http://i.stack.imgur.com/6cluO.jpg

Comment: @johnrao07 for status bar and toolbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code Corrected**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tool_bar_test);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

}

**Set The Theme in your ToolBar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:popupTheme="@style/<Your Theme Name>"
app:theme="@style/<Your Theme Name>"/>
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I use this sample for both themes ?

Comment: you've got two folders >v21 and <v21 , you named the two themes same , so android studio does the stuff for you which one to pick

Comment: I got Shut Down VM on Android 5 (

Comment: done. If I comment this line: setTheme(R.style.DriverNotesAppTheme); I got shut down vm on 5 android too. Log cat - just shutting down VM.

Comment: I try it but I got shut down. I comment this line but it doesn't help me(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96032/discussion-between-johnrao07-and-artem-shevchenko).